# Trying to compare a HashSet element with an element in a List

Tags: java, list, hashset

I have a HashSet that I created and this is what it contains. It will contain more later on, this is pasted from standard out when I did a toString on it. Just to show the contents.

```
foo.toString(): Abstractfoo [id=2, serial=1d21d, value=1.25, date=2012-09-02 12:00:00.0]
INFO  [STDOUT] price.toString(): Abstractfoo [id=1, serial=1d24d, value=1.30, date=2012-09-19 12:00:00.0]
```

I have a List that I also have and I need to compare the two. One of the elements in List is:

```
Bar.toString(): Bar [id=1d21d, name=Dell, description=Laptop, ownerId=null]
```

Here is what I am trying to do...

Bar contains all of the elements I want foo to have. There will only be one unique serial. I would like my program to see if an element in the list that is in HashSet contains the id for bar. So serial == id.

Here is what I've been trying to do

**Removed code and added clearer code below**

I've verified the data is getting entered into the HashSet and List correctly by viewing it through the debugger.

foo is being pulled from a database through hibernate, and bar is coming from a different source. If there is an element in bar I need to add it to a list and I'm passing it back to my UI where I'll enter some additional data and then commit it to the database.

Let me know if this makes sense and if I can provide anymore information.
Thanks

EDIT: Here is the class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/system", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<AbstractSystem> SystemList() {

        // Retrieve system list from database
        HashSet<AbstractSystem> systemData = new HashSet<AbstractSystem>(
                systemService.getSystemData());

        // Retrieve system info from cloud API
        List<SystemName> systemName= null;
        try {
            systemName = cloudClass.getImages();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.warn("Unable to get status", e);
        }
            
                // Tried this but, iter2 only has two items and iter has many more.
                // In production it will be the other way around, but I need to not 
                // Have to worry about that
        Iterator<SystemName> iter = systemName.iterator();
        Iterator<AbstractSystem> iter2 = systemData .iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Image temp = iter.next();
            while(iter2.hasNext()){
                AbstractPricing temp2 = iter2.next();
                System.out.println("temp2.getSerial(): " + temp2.getSerial());
                System.out.println("temp.getId(): " + temp.getId());
                if(temp2.getSerial().equals(temp.getId())){
                    System.out.println("This will be slow...");
                }
            }
        }

        return systemData;
    }
```

Comment: You should try to make that clearer. SHow us the declaration of your Set and the one of your List. Show us what they contain. explain in a clearer way what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to decide if an instance of `Foo` is "equal" to an instance of `Bar`, given some definition of "equal" (possibly based on the value of `serialId`?).  If that's the case, just write a method that takes one argument of each type and returns a boolean if they're equal based on whatever criteria you want.

Comment: I added the whole class, it should be a little more clear. An instance of foo and an instance of bar is a list. I need to see if one element is equal to another in each list.

Comment: That catch of the general `Exception` isn't really handling the exception and is actually setting up for a `NullPointerException` in the code below it. Perhaps let the exception propagate instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If N is the number of items in `systemName` and M is the number of items in `systemData`, then you've effectively built an O(N*M) method.

If you instead represent your `systemData` as a `HashMap` of `AbstractSystem` by `AbstractSystem.getSerial()` values, then you just loop through the `systemName` collection and lookup by `systemName.getId()`.  This becomes more like O(N+M).

(You might want to avoid variables like `iter`, `iter2`, `temp2`, etc., since those make the code harder to read.)

**EDIT** - here's what I mean:

```
// Retrieve system list from database
HashMap<Integer, AbstractSystem> systemDataMap = new HashMap<AbstractSystem>(
            systemService.getSystemDataMap());

// Retrieve system info from cloud API
List<SystemName> systemNames = cloudClass.getImages();
for (SystemName systemName : systemNames) {
    if (systemDataMap.containsKey(systemName.getId()) {
        System.out.println("This will be slow...");
    }
}
```

I used Integer because I can't tell from your code what the type of `AbstractSystem.getSerial()` or `SystemName.getId()` are.  This assumes that you store the system data as a `Map` elsewhere.  If not, you could construct the map yourself here.

Comment: How do I switch the representation of my HashMap to what you are proposing?